# Error al desplegar proyecto de react en amplify

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, aws

Estoy tratando de desplegar un proyecto de React en Amplify desde Gitlab, funciona correctamente al probarlo en local, pero al tratar de desplegar solo se muestra la página en blanco [enlace](https://master.d1462b8wb93f82.amplifyapp.com/).

La ruta inicial en el localhost es **http://localhost:3001/Login**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que agregar la ruta donde va estar alojado tu proyecto, los recursos de javascript y css no los encuentra el navegador porque los esta buscando en esta ruta **/DesarrolloInnova/webappfrontend/static/js/main.96135afb.chunk.js** y realmente estan en **https://master.d1462b8wb93f82.amplifyapp.com/static/css/main.96135afb.chunk.js** para consigurar esto debes entrar a tu `package.json` ys buscar donde esta (si no esta ponerla) la propiedad `"homepage"` y ahi poner el valor del dominio que vas a usar por ejemplo

*package.json*

```
{
 ....,
 "homepage" : "https://master.d1462b8wb93f82.amplifyapp.com/"
}
```

para que los recursos cargen desde ahi

luego de hacer los cambios, volver a generar el build